# I keep getting the LNK2019 error and I'm not sure how to fix it

Tags: c++

Here's My entire program. The error I keep getting is:

*Error  LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl getPIN(class std::vector<int,class std::allocator >)" (?getPIN@@YAXV?$vector@HV?$allocator@H@std@@@std@@@Z) referenced in function main*

I'm not really sure what the problem is or what I'm doing wrong here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

// Function Prototype
bool testPIN(vector<int>, vector<int>);
void getPIN(vector<int>);

int main()
{
    vector<int> databasePIN { 2, 4, 1, 8, 7, 9, 0 }; // Base set of values.
    vector<int> customerPIN(7);

    getPIN(databasePIN);
    
}


bool testPIN(vector<int> custPIN,vector<int> databasePIN)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < databasePIN.size(); index++) {
        if (custPIN.at(index) != databasePIN.at(index))
            return false; // We've found two different values.
    }
    return true; // If we make it this far, the values are the same.
}

void getPin(vector<int> custPIN)
{
    int input;
    for (int index = 0; index < custPIN.size(); index++) {
        cin >> input;
        custPIN.push_back(input);
    }

}
```

Comment: getPIN != getPin

Answer (score 1):

you have defined

```
void getPin(vector<int> custPIN)
---------^^
{
    int input;
    for (int index = 0; index < custPIN.size(); index++) {
        cin >> input;
        custPIN.push_back(input);
    }
}
```

but call getPIN